# Pandas Series of lists of strings how to count and append to df per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, series

**Summarize the problem**

I have a Dataframe with a Series of lists of strings.
I can use a Counter from 'collections' to iterate over each row of the series and count the times each string appeared easy enough:

```
for list_of_strings in df['info']:
    counter = Counter()
    for string in list_of_strings:
        counter[string]+=1
```

What I want is to mutate the df to now have as many columns as there were unique strings found in all of the lists of strings in the df['info'] series. The column names would be the string value.

For each row in the df, the new columns values would either be 0 if the string was not found or N where N is the count of how many times the string was found in that rows list_of_strings

**Describe what you’ve tried**

I was able to make a df whose # and name of columns matches the unique strings found, but I cant figure out how to append the counts per row, and Im not even sure if crafting and appending to a brand new dataframe is the right way to go about it?:

```
unique_df = pd.Series(copy_df['info'].explode().unique()).to_frame().T
```

I tried doing something using df.at() for each counter key but it exploded my juptyr notebook :\

Any help is appreciated, let me know what other info I can provide.

Comment: It helps to have an example we can copy of your input dataframe, and an example output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @lummers, the Series is of the form pd.Series([['A','B','A'],['C','B'],['D']]) as assumed in the answer below. Thank you for keeping me aware of what to provide for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this input Series:

```
s = pd.Series([['A','B','A'],['C','B'],['D']])
```

You can `explode`, `groupby.value_counts` and `unstack` with a `fill_value` of 0:

```
(s.explode()
  .groupby(level=0)
  .value_counts()
  .unstack(fill_value=0)
  .reindex(s.index, fill_value=0)
)
```

Or use `crosstab`:

```
s2 = s.explode()

(pd.crosstab(s2.index, s2)
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  0  0
1  0  1  1  0
2  0  0  0  1
```